# IE10, IFrame : some of the cookies are not sent. P3P?

Tags: iframe, cookies, dynamics-crm-2011, postmessage, p3p

I am prototyping a hosted MS Dynamics CRM based application and have some issue with the cookie based federated authentication and IE10. What I wanna achieve is how FB/Google auth works: I open a window, the user authenticates on the MSPortal then after closing the auth window the custom site communicates over IFrames and postMessages protocol. This works for all browsers but IE10 and possible IE9 clients. When opening the iframe after authentication IE10 does not send all cookies back (although does send some). Namely it is not sending the MSISAuth and MSISAuth2 cookes.

I have run into articles about P3P but at this point I am not sure if it is a P3P question at all, since 2 of the 4 cookies are actually sent.